# IIS 8.5 Setting Custom Error Pages and Redirects

Tags: iis-8.5, custom-errors

My environment consists of multiple websites, each with their own app pool running .NET v 2.0 Integrated.  All of the sites share the same web.config.  My question is whenever I change a custom error page, ie 404 for example, for one site, it changes it on ALL of the web sites.  My suspicion is this is because of the shared web.config and the app pools running Integrated.  I imagine there is a creative work around for this but haven't found anything obvious searching the internet.  Can someone shed some light on this?  Thank you.

Comment: how do your websites all share the same web.config?

all websites are mapped back to the same folder on disk?

or do you mean by multiple websites that they are subfolders under a single web root?

it is pretty common for each website or even multiple applications/folders under a single website to have their own custom error pages.

Comment: websites don't share a web.config though they do share an applicationHost.config. Do you have a single website with multiple folders converted to applications?